# Прервать выполнение js функции в if

Tags: javascript, jquery, прокрутка

Пытаюсь сделать поблочный скролл, но че-т на ерунде застопорился.

Сильно не ругайте, я много гуглил, честно, разобраться не получается.

```js
var n = 1;
window.onscroll = function scr() {

  if (n == 1) {
    var target = $(".2");
    var target_top = target.offset().top;
    $('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: target_top
    }, 900);
    n = n + 1;
    return; //хочу, чтоб здесь выполнение функции прекращалось
  }

  if (n == 2) {
    var target = $(".3");
    var target_top = target.offset().top;
    $('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: target_top
    }, 900);
    n = n + 2;
  }
}
```

```css
div {
  height: 700px;
}
```

```html
<div class="1">1</div>
<div class="2">2</div>
<div class="3">3</div>
```

[jsfiddle - вот здесь листните результат](https://jsfiddle.net/g5u6pkvz/)

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Выполнение функции в данном месте действительно прекращается. Другой вопрос, что при вызове анимации скролла, триггерится событие `'scroll'` объекта `window`, что вызывает дальнейший скроллинг. У вызовов анимации в jQuery, как правило, есть возможность добавить callback последним аргументом, который будет вызван по завершению анимации.

```js
window.onscroll = (function() {
  var n = 1;
  var isAnimating = false;

  var reenableAnimate = function(nextN) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      isAnimating = false;
      n = nextN;
    }, 0);
  };

  var animate = function(targetClass, time, nextN) {
    isAnimating = true;
    time = time || 900;
    var target = $(targetClass);
    var targetTop = target.offset().top;
    $('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: targetTop
    }, time, function() {
      reenableAnimate(nextN);
    });
  };

  return function scr(e) {
    if (isAnimating) return;
    if (n == 1) return animate('.2', 900, n + 1);
    if (n == 2) return animate('.3', 900, n + 2);
  }
})();
```

```css
div {
  height: 700px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="1">1</div>
<div class="2">2</div>
<div class="3">3</div>
```

- Обернул функцию, чтобы нужные ей переменные не лежали в глобальной области видимости.
- Добавил переменную `isAnimating` - текущее состояние анимации скроллинга.
- `n`, теперь изменяется после завершения анимации
- `reenableAnimate` внутри вызова имеет `setTimeout`, без него анимация включалась раньше, чем шло фактическое завершение скроллинга.

Upd: избавился от скачка в хроме, заодно добавил возможность прокрутки, если элемент не влазит во viewport. Так же чуток подправил с учетом использования jQuery. Новая версия https://jsfiddle.net/yd47aqas/26/

Comment: не могу избежать комментария "спасибо", потому сам год бы год шел к этому коду, так что спасибо!

Comment: в хроме, перед тем как страница прокручивается к нужному элементу, сначала происходит скачок, не подскажите, как этого избежать?

Comment: Завтра на работе посмотрю

Comment: под "скачком" имеется в виду стандартная прокрутка хрома на ~100px , для примера: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qu1mk39d/)

Comment: бесконечно благодарен вам за помощь; теперь чувствую себя обязанным идти и помогать другим чем могу